# Closing window in swift

Tags: macos, swift3

I have a collection view and each item opens a new window with a slideshow.

The segue kind is "show" and it's opened with:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "showGalleryPlayer", sender: self)
```

My idea is when double click another item the window with the previous slideshow close and the new one opens. I don't know how to do it or if it is the right approach. I want only one window with the slideshow at a time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When performing a segue, the following method will be invoked:

```
func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```

Just override this method in whichever class you perform the segue and use the provided `NSStoryboardSegue` object to retrieve a reference to the newly opened window (after matching the segue's `identifier` of course). Store the reference to the window and use it to close the window before opening the next one.

Comment: Great! I know how to use prepare(for segue:) But how do I retrieve a reference to the newly opened window? Sorry I'm just starting with coding.

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsstoryboardsegue). `NSStoryboardSegue` has a property `destinationController` that will be your `NSViewController` containing the slideshow. Your new window will be the viewcontroller's view's `window`.